# What happens to melatonin and the circadian rythm when one adopts biphasic sleep cycle?

Tags: sleep-cycles

I have read that the sleep cycle is driven by melatonin, and that there is a 
natural 24h "sine-wave" of melatonin, where during the day, melatonin is at low levels, while during the night, it is at high levels.

However, I'm wondering, if one adopts a biphasic sleep cycle, where one e.g. sleeps 4 hours during the night and 4 hours during the afternoon, or 6 hours during the night and 2 hours during the afternoon, **will that turn the circadian rythm/melatonin-sine-wave into a "double-frequency sine wave"**? i.e. will there be a bumb in melatonin during your afternoon nap?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, something quite similar to what you hypothesize in fact!

According to this study (unfortunately, behind a paywall): [In short photoperiods, human sleep is biphasic.](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/10607034) (Literally the title of the research paper.)

> When normal individuals were transferred from a conventional 16-h
>   photoperiod to an experimental 10-h photo-period, their sleep episodes
>   expanded and usually divided into two symmetrical bouts, several hours
>   in duration, with a 1-3 h waking interval between them. The durations
>   of nocturnal melatonin secretion and of the nocturnal phase of rising
>   sleepiness (measured in a constant routine protocol) also expanded,
>   indicating that the timing of internal processes that control sleep
>   and melatonin, such as circadian rhythms, had been modified by the
>   change in photoperiod.

WEHR, T. A. (1992), In short photoperiods, human sleep is biphasic. Journal of Sleep Research, 1: 103–107. doi:10.1111/j.1365-2869.1992.tb00019.x

Comment: Is there a solution for teenagers who regularly sleep in really late resulting in short photoperiods?

Comment: Solution as in a "normalized" melatonin schedule? Some people take melatonin, but I've heard a person can build tolerance to it. Exercise seems to be the general consensus of experts in the area of sleep.
I suppose this is the problem you're talking about:
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2820578/

Comment: Yes, a way to fix that!